# Clicking the button does not trigger Confirm-box popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [jQuery confirm box plugin](http://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/) and want to trigger it on anchor-click event. The code I use does not work:

```
<a href="javascript:addData();" class="btn btn-primary btn-block example-p-2">Add Grid</a>


function addData(){
    $('.example-p-2').on('click', function () {
        $.confirm({
            confirmButtonClass: 'btn-info',
            cancelButtonClass: 'btn-danger'
        });
    });
}
```

When i click on the button above, it should open a small fancy confirm box, but instead it reloads the page. I also get an error: `object cant find property`.

Please correct me.

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="pretty.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-confirm.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the event default behaviour, in this case its an `a` element thus it will try to naviate to the `href` you provide. You can prevent this by doing `evt.preventDefault()`. You also dont need the function definition.

Replace your code from:

```
function addData(){
    $('.example-p-2').on('click', function () {
        $.confirm({
            confirmButtonClass: 'btn-info',
            cancelButtonClass: 'btn-danger'
        });
    });
}
```

to:

```
 $('.example-p-2').on('click', function (evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      $.confirm({
           confirmButtonClass: 'btn-info',
           cancelButtonClass: 'btn-danger'
      });
 });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle with your example?

Answer (score 0):

Your addData() function is only adding the event listener to the button the first time it's called, to show your confirm popup you should use directly

```
$('.example-p-2').on('click', function () {
                                $.confirm({
                                    confirmButtonClass: 'btn-info',
                                    cancelButtonClass: 'btn-danger'
                                });

                            });
```

and your button should look like

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block example-p-2">Add Grid</a>
```

---

Here's a working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wKPAaiZAafJ44XZLfMtt)

Comment: Now getting-Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'confirm'

Comment: Can you show me your code ? how you are including the JQuery confirm plugin ?
I think you're not loading your plugin properly.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-block example-p-2">Add Grid</a>

<script>
    $('.example-p-2').on('click', function () {
        $.confirm({
            confirmButtonClass: 'btn-info',
            cancelButtonClass: 'btn-danger'
         });
     });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nzezu5zy/

Comment: getting now-Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'confirm'

Comment: Yeah, `$.confirm()` is not part of jQuery, so without knowing what other libraries you're using, it's difficult to say.

Comment: @micheal This works as expected, look at [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nzezu5zy/4/).

Comment: @micheal Have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/nzezu5zy/3/ ha, skobaljic beat me to it, same solution.

Comment: @ skobaljic-I can see that it working there.I tried with the same piece of code and same js file i attached.But didnt work.Is there something else need to be attached

Comment: That's all that needs to be attached, but maybe adding your code to the jsFiddle will help us discover where your problem is

Comment: i shared the libraries which i m adding

Comment: yep, but doesn't the jsFiddle use those same libraries too? (not bootstrap or pretty), but it uses jquery and jquery-confirm no?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

```
<a id='addData' class="btn btn-primary btn-block example-p-2">Add Grid</a>

$('#addData').bind('click',function(){


});
```